# DRYing up classes that duplicate methods

Tags: python

I have various classes `Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3`, etc. all of which contain this exact piece of content inside:

```
def showName(self):
   openWindow()
   print self.name
```

For example:

```
class Class1:
    # SOME CODE

    def showName(self):
       openWindow()
       print self.name

    # SOME MORE CODE
```

What is the best way to have `showName` defined once in a separate file and import it back to `Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3`, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derive from this [mixin](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin):

```
class NameShowMixin(object):
    def showName(self):
        openWindow()
        print self.name
```

Or make it a separate function, in case you intend `name` to be a public member.

Comment: Thanks! (Lol for the mobile version of Wikipedia.) Once I have the mixin, how do I "mix it back in" the original classes?

Comment: @Randomblue: just let `Class1` and friends derive from `NameShowMixin`. Well-written mixins like this trivial one can safely be used with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

The mixin class idea presented by larsmans is the canonical way to do it. An alternative way is to put the function in another module and import it into each class definition:

```
class Class1(object):
    from mixins import showName
    # other definitions here
```

Your call as to whether this is clearer than multiple inheritance.